# Handle http requests in different class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, handle, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to create a class which contains different method, each one of these methods will perform some http requests operations and return a result to the caller method.

for example:

```
UserOperations *op = [[UserOperations alloc] init];
int age = [op getUserAge];
```

the method `"getUserAge"` will call a web service and do some xml parsing to return a value (the age) to the caller.

what's the best and right way to implement it.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa - Return information from NSOperation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297733/cocoa-return-information-from-nsoperation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `delegate` pattern here.

See `Protocols and delegates` in iOS. Please visit [here](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) and [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1)

And, also see a similar question asked on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978621/nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue-callback)

Answer (score 0):

for every webservice, you should have to separate it from your controller, and then separate the controller from your UI class.

like

UILayer
//invoke method of controller class and pass the delegate of viewController and selector to which at the end you want to return

Control Layer
// get the data along with delegate to UIlayer and selector to uiLayer, and call the webservice

Webservice Layer
// receive the data from controll layer, call the webservice from server, get the response and pass to parser layer along with its delegate(webservice)

Parser Layer
// get data from webervice layer and parse it

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

now you are going back

// webservice layer has the delegate stored in it that to UI layer along with the selecter, after parsing the responsed data, it will call the UILayer with the parsed data.

// ui layer will display/process it